# Integrate $x^y(1-x)^z$

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to calculate $$\int x^{y}(1-x)^z \, \mathrm dx.$$ I tried to integrate by parts, but it will still leave me a similar structure. I wonder if there is any easy ways to solve this?

Comment: What are $y$ and $z$?

Comment: Check out [the incomplete Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $z \in\mathbb{N}$, one can use the binomial expansion formula inside of the integral
$$(1-x)^z=\sum_{k=0}^z\binom{z}{k}(-x)^k$$
$$\therefore\int  x^{y}(1-x)^zdx=\int x^y\sum_{k=0}^z\binom{z}{k}(-x)^kdx$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^z(-1)^k\binom{z}{k}\int x^{y+k}dx$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^z(-1)^k\binom{z}{k}\frac{x^{y+k+1}}{y+k+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

The integral can be written as follows:

$$\int x^y(1-x)^z dx=\int (x^{\frac{y}{z}}-x^{\frac{y}{z}+1})^z dx $$

Now we make this substitution $\frac{y}{z}=\alpha$:

$$\int (x^{\alpha}-x^{\alpha+1})^z dx$$

By Newton binomial formula:

$$\int \sum_{i=0}^{z} (x^\alpha)^{z-i}(-x^{\alpha+1})^i \binom{z}{i}=\sum_{i=0}^{z} (-1)^i\binom{z}{i}\int (x^{i+\alpha z})  dx=$$ $$=\sum_{i=0}^{z} (-1)^i\binom{z}{i}\frac{x^{i+\alpha z+1}}{i+\alpha z+1} $$

And substituting $\alpha$ :

$$\int x^y(1-x)^z dx=\sum_{i=0}^{z} (-1)^i\binom{z}{i}\frac{x^{i+y+1}}{i+y+1} $$

:)